# The following error occurred while opening the file '\\?\E:\TempDB\MDTempStore_1584_1_j1pv2.tmp': Access is denied

Tags: sql-server, tempdb

I'm trying to start a fresh install of TFS 2013 but running into the issue TF255356: The following error occurred when configuring the Team Foundation databases: TF400711: Error occurred while executing servicing step Create Warehouse for component InstallWarehouse during Install: Create Analysis Database schema failed: Error generating Analysis Database: File system error: The following error occurred while opening the file '\?\E:\TempDB\MDTempStore_1584_1_j1pv2.tmp': Access is denied.

I have tried to remove the read-only flag from the tempdb folder but it keeps getting set to true after applying the change. I have also added the registry entry UseSystemForSystemFolders which allows read-only to be removed from the folder but it does not persist.

Any help with this would be great

Thanks

Chris

Comment: Please check accounts which are used for running of SqlServer and analysis services and check that these accounts have access to \?\E:\TempDB folder.

Comment: the accounts that are used for running both sql server and analysis services both have access this folder.

Comment: The user I have created has all of the admin rights to the relevant tables. I have also gone into the service and made sure that this user can log a process in the security policy. I have also made sure that the user can create, modify, update on the temp db folder. Locally on the security policy for the temp db folder I have added this user. However every time I reset the read-only flag it just keeps going back on.  I'm not sure what more I can do.